# Why does my test fail because it cannot find the redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme, router

I am trying to test if my app routes render the correct components and I get this error:

```
Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(withRouter())". Either wrap the root component
 in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(withRouter())
 in connect options.
```

After looking up for solutions on the internet I couldn't figure out how to solve this. I get this error in all of my test for all components. Initially, I thought this is related to how withRouter is reacting when wrapped in connect(), but it is not.

How can I overcome this error, since my redux app was working perfectly before, frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a test provider for testing, which will use the same providers as the application. For example:

```
  const TestProviders = ({ store, children }) => (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18nInstance}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
          </Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    </I18nextProvider>
  )
```

and if you are testing a component, you must use the same providers as in the application.

```
const createComponent = (store, component) =>
  shallow(
    <TestProviders store={store}>
      {component}
    </TestProviders>,
  )
```

I will proposed solution for you:

```
let store = createStore(rootReducer)

const createComponent = async (store, props) =>
  mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <TestedComponent {...props} />
    </Provider>,
  )
```

next you can use createComponent func in your tests

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems a bit exaggerated. Could you explain in a few words what the reasoning is behind all that? Where did you pull all that i18nInstance component?

Comment: I've added a large number of providers for the example, you don't have to use all of them. You just need to wrap the components that you are testing in providers in those providers that are used in your application

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the Routes with the Provider and pass store as a prop so that it could be accessible through different routes

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Routes />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: My main component - App - is already wrapped with a Provider with a store.

Comment: At this point the app is too complex with too many components and it would take a while to reproduce it so I can share it. But if you want to know something about how I set up things, I will gladly answer to you.

Comment: Would you be able to show me at least the provider implementation and also the routes implementation where you use withRouter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const reducer = ()=>{
  ...
}

const store = createStore(reducer)

 ...
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
 ...
```